# Selecting option inside Android WebView using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, select, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to populate a form inside a loaded and displayed WebView on Android.
Populating `<input >` fields works fine... I do this in the WebViewClient's onPageFinished method:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('input1').value='"+desired_value+"';"        );
}
```

However, trying to select an option for a `<select id="select1" ... >` tag doesn't seem to work as I would expect:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('select1').selected='1';");
```

I also tried:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('select1').value='1';");
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?
If I press the select on the WebView surface, Android pops up a selection menu of the options, and upon selecting, the WebView updates with the chosen value, so I'm hoping this can be done.  Also, the attached onChange JavaScript function executes, which I also want to achieve.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I must mention that I don't have extensive JavaScript knowledge, so I apologize if there is some obvious easy answer).
Thanks

Comment: have you tried: javascript:document.getElementById('select1').value=1; ?

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to work:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('select1').value='1';");
```

And then manually calling the onChange function, which doesn't get triggered by the value assignment:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {select1_changed(1);})()");
```

There may be a better way, but this works for me for now.
Tin

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
wbv.loadUrl("javascript:(function() 
{document.getElementById('select1').value='1'})()");
```